# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in wp-config.php

Tags: mysql, wordpress, parsing

I am trying to setup my first WP Db on my localhost, but when I run it on the browser, I get this error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-config.php on line 22**

I've checked the settings and didn't change anything that I wasn't suppose to, but I still get this error.

What am I missing in the following php??

```
`**// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //'

`/** The name of the database for WordPress */`
define('DB_NAME', wordpress_test');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8_unicode_ci');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');**
```

Comment: syntax highlighting says it all.

Comment: Could you at least tell us which line is line 22?

Answer (score 3):

change

```
define('DB_NAME', wordpress_test');
```

to

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress_test');
```

Comment: nDudani,  Thanks very much for finding the "tiny" problem. I really appreciate it... it's the small things that create the biggest problems and it's always nice when someone else looks at it and can point it out.  Cheers... Monaleasaa

Comment: can you please select correct answer from list?

Answer (score 1):

```
`**// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //' <-- there we see a lost quote...
//It should be ` I think...

`/** The name of the database for WordPress */`
define('DB_NAME', wordpress_test');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8_unicode_ci');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');**
```